# \input{} give error when only entering part of a command

Tags: input

I have a `main.tex` file, which in the preamble contains the following path definition

```
\def\commonpath{C:/Users/Default/Documents/Folder}
```

This compiles just fine. If I break the code into separate lines as such:

```
\def\commonpath{%
   C:/Users/Default/Documents/Folder%
}
```

Everything compiles just fine as well.

What I would like to  do is to take the path out into a separate file. For example, I would like to create a file `folderpath.tex` and place it in the same directory as `main.tex`. `folderpath.tex` should contain only the following line:

```
C:/Users/Default/Documents/Folder
```

Then, in `main.tex` I would like to have something like

```
\def\commonpath{%
   \input{folderpath.tex}%
}
```

However when I do that and try to compile I get a `missing \begin{document}` error.

How can I get around this problem? I thought that the `\input{}` command takes literally the content of the file that is being inputted.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `expl3` rather easily:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\file_get:nnN { folderpath.tex } {} \commonpath
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use `\input{folderpath}`  and have `folderpath.tex` contain `\def\commonpath{a/b/c}`

If you `\input` a file that contains `a/b/c` then you have to be careful about white space from ends of lines, and non-expandable tokens typically inserted at the end of the file, from `\par` or the file hook code.

Answer (score 1):

The approach `\def\commonpath{\input{folderpath}}` should not be used for several reasons:

1. `\input` is a quite complex command in LaTeX;
2. the primitive `\input`, available as `\@@input` is not a simple command either;
3. you would anyway access the file system at each call of `\commonpath`.

Why is `\input` made complex in LaTeX? Because it's not only opening a file, reading it in and closing it is actually needed:

- the syntax of the command is modified so it conforms to the standard syntax (which the primitive `\input` doesn't):
- LaTeX wants to keep track of the input files;
- some other details…

Why not `\@@input`, then? Because of what TeX does to input files, for instance it adds a space at the end of lines (the standard `\endlinechar`, to be precise, which gets usually converted to a space).

You could use the `catchfile` package and do

`\CatchFileDef\commonpath{folderpath}{}`

(don't forget the trailing `{}`), or the [mentioned `expl3` way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/620991/4427) (likely preferable). Doing so will avoid accessing the file system more than once.